# Ngrx action does not complete after an error is executed

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

### Action does not complete correctly after an error occurs

In my application I created an action to delete a user, however before deleting this user is informed a `Dialog` on the screen asking to inform the administrator password, if the administrator password is correct then it deletes the user.

My problem is when the administrator password is incorrect incorrect I call an action to say that the password entered is not valid and after that moment I can no longer complete the action by entering a valid password.

**Sequence of shares:**

> [User] delete user;
>
> [Auth] reauthenticate user;
>
> [Auth] reauthenticate error (password is invalid);
>
> [Auth] reauthenticate user
>
> [Auth] reauthenticate user
>
> [Auth] reauthenticate user
>
> **NO SUCCESS AND NO ERROR**

**Problem:** After this occurs when I try to call the reauthentication action again with a valid password, only the `Reauthenticate` function is called but it is not detected that this action completed successfully.

I have seen in some source information about using [Ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) that in a way how an `@Effect` is created to listen to the call of the action, after the call is made and an error occurs this action can no longer be called again returning success.

**Can this be true?**

**usuarios.effects.ts:**

```
@Effect()
deleteUser$: Observable<Action> = this._action$.ofType(userActions.DELETE)
    .map((action: userActions.Delete) => action)
    .switchMap(data => {
        return this._userService.deleteUser(data.payload);
    })
    .map(() => new userActions.DeleteSuccess())
    .catch((err) => {
        return Observable.of(new userActions.DeleteError({error: err}));
    });
```

**usuarios.service.ts:**

```
deleteUser(user: IUser): Observable<void> {

    const reautenticateUser = this._modalService.create({
        nzTitle: 'Delete user',
        nzContent: ReauthenticateUserComponent,
        nzFooter: [{
            type: 'danger',
            label: 'Cancel',
            onClick: (componentInstance) => {
                componentInstance.closeDialog();
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'primary',
            label: 'Ok',
            onClick: (componentInstance) => {
                componentInstance.reauthenticateUser();
            },
            disabled: (componentInstance) => {
                return componentInstance.adminPassword.invalid;
            },
        }
        ]
    });

    return reautenticateUser.afterClose
        .switchMap((authenticated: boolean) => {

            if (authenticated) {
                const ref = this._angularFirestore
                    .doc<IProfissional | IRecepcionista>(`users/${usuario.id}`);

                return Observable.fromPromise(ref.delete()).map(() => {
                    this._message.info('User deleted success', {
                        nzDuration: 5000,
                        nzPauseOnHover: true,
                        nzAnimate: true
                    });
                });
            }

            throw new Error('Password invalid');
        });
}
```

**NOTE:** When the action of deleting a user is completed successfully, I can perform the action again without any problem.

**Running in the sequence below, I have no problems:**

> [User] delete user;
>
> [Auth] reauthenticate user;
>
> [Auth] reauthenticate success (password is valid);
>
> [User] delete user success;
>
> [User] delete user;
>
> [Auth] reauthenticate user;
>
> [Auth] reauthenticate success (password is valid);
>
> **CONTINUE ...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the Observable completes when it catches an error. You have to catch the error internally so that the external Observable continues to emit:

```
.mergeMap(data =>
    this._userService.deleteUser(data.payload)
    .map(() => new userActions.DeleteSuccess())
    .catch((err) =>
        Observable.of(new userActions.DeleteError({error: err}))
    )        
)
```

I've switched to `mergeMap` you probably don't want to cancel a delete action with another delete action. Also, if you want to use RxJS 6:

```
mergeMap(data =>
    this._userService.deleteUser(data.payload).pipe(
        map(() => new userActions.DeleteSuccess()),
        catchError((err) =>
          of(new userActions.DeleteError({error: err}))
        }),
    )
)
```

Comment: I changed the way you put it and it's still the same ... it's not working for me

Comment: I have made several changes in my @ Effect and also made changes in the service but after an error it is nothing more than `reauthenticate ();`

Answer (score 0):

when I returned the `err` I received the message below and nothing else worked after that:

`ERROR Error: Detected unserializable action at "error"`

I was able to solve by returning the `err.message` instead of the `err`.

```
mergeMap(data =>
  this._userService.deleteUser(data.payload).pipe(
    map(() => new userActions.DeleteSuccess()),
    catchError((err) =>
      of(new userActions.DeleteError({error: err.message}))
    }),
  )
)
```